# Are "anti-surge resistors" just regular resistors?

Tags: datasheet, specifications

I am looking for high-power SMT resistor, and found [this guy](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ROHM-Semiconductor/ESR18EZPF1690?qs=493kPxzlxfL5k1Qdcsnlqg%3D%3D):

[image: photo from datasheet]

My question is: what does "anti-surge" mean, in the context of a resistor? Is it just the suggested application (a crowbar circuit, perhaps)? Can I use a 1/2W "anti-surge resistors" in a circuit that is constantly dissipating power?

Comment: Some resistor types have much better surge ratings than others; carbon composition (or the modern replacement, ceramic composition) resistors, for instance, can withstand thousands of times their power rating in surge events, but that would obliterate a thin-film resistor.

Comment: What you can and cannot use it for: that's exactly in that data sheet!

Comment: an anti surge for just dissipating power is simply wasted, it will work fine

Answer (score 7):

It means the resistor has been built to better survive momentary current/heat/power spikes than a typical resistor. A normal 1/2W resistor might die when exposed to an intense, short term current spike whereas an anti-surge resistor might survive even though they both handle 1/2W continuously.

It's about hot spots generated in that short interval of time before the heat can spread out and equilibriate. Designing the resistor so the heat is generated over a larger area and more evenly to begin allows higher tolerance to transient power dissipation and selecting materials that are more stable at high temperatures does too.

Answer (score 6):

An anti-surge resistor is designed so that resistive heating occurs in the whole volume of the resistive material, rather than generating hot-spots by heating just parts of it unevenly.

It's quite easy to make a surge-fragile resistor when trimming its value by making cuts across the film. The narrowing caused by the cut, and the uneven field around the tip of the cut combine to cause much of the heating to occur in the small region around the tip. This region will often heat up excessively and go to a higher resistance, which will cause the cut to grow, and zip across the resistor.

Ideally anti-surge resistors are made without trimming. If they are trimmed, then it's by the more expensive process of thinning the film uniformly, rather than cutting across.

Wire-wound resistors tend to have a much better surge rating than film resistors of the same steady state power, as the wire tends to have higher mass, and so thermal capacity, than the film. Although the film can heat the substrate, it can take fractions of a second for the heat to conduct, useless in the case of short pulses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a IEC standard for anti-surge resistors but usually they have some special characteristics:

- They handle *voltage* peaks over their nominal value better (without arching); there's a SOA diagram for that, usually
- By consequence they tolerate *power* peaks over their nominal: while a standard resistor resists usually five times the power for 5s there are surge resistor designed to withstand 20 times the power;
- Often they are wirewound and/or fusible resistors: this has implications on safety and reliability
- On the bad side often they have lousy tolerances, thermal drifts and so on but it doesn't matter for their typical use cases.

Comment: The wirewound ones usually have abysmal ESL, too. I wish they still made carbon comp resistors...

Comment: @Hearth They do but are $1 a pop. Carbon film MELF are the next closest and cost about the same. Then ceramic which are dozens of times more expensive :S

Comment: They still make carbon composition resistor, just not in SMD. Mouser has a whole subcategory for them